# Problem with Bitmap Cloning

Tags: c#, exception, bitmap, clone

Consider this code for loading, modifying and saving a Bitmap image:

```
    using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap("C:\\test.jpg"))
    {
        bmp.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipNone);
        bmp.Save("C:\\test.jpg");
    }
```

it runs without any exception.
But consider this one:

```
    using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap("C:\\test.jpg"))
    {
        using (Bitmap bmpClone = (Bitmap)bmp.Clone())
        {
            //You can replace "bmpClone" in the following lines with "bmp",
            //exception occurs anyway                    
            bmpClone.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipNone);
            bmpClone.Save("C:\\test.jpg");
        }
    }
```

It ends in an ExternalException with this message: "A generic error occurred in GDI+".
What's wrong here? Any kind of lock on opened file? If so, why the first block works? What is the proper code for cloning a System.Drawing.Bitmap while we may need to edit main object or its clone in the memory and still have them both loaded in memory?

Comment: Any difference if you use `Bitmap bmpClone = new Bitmap(bmp)` ?

Comment: @dtb: No, the same exception occurs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could also load the bitmap without file locking using the simple workaround:

```
using (Stream s = File.OpenRead(@"\My Documents\My Pictures\Waterfall.jpg"))
Bitmap _backImage = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromStream(s);
```

Comment: Bitmap.FromStream returns Image. Why do you assume that it can be casted to a Bitmap?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the file is locked when the first bitmap object is loaded and thus `bmpClone.Save()` to the same file fails because you have a logical deadlock.

When opening Bitmaps by filename, the file is locked throughout the life of the Bitmap. If you use a stream, the stream must remain open.

**Update**:

If you wish to have two bitmaps in memory for use outside of the scope of the method you are in, then you won't be using a `using` block.

Create the first image from file, and then clone it. Utilize them as needed throughout your UI lifecycle but make sure you clean them up using `Dispose()` when they are no longer needed so that underlying resources are released.

Also, from MSDN:

> Saving the image to the same file it
>   was constructed from is not allowed
>   and throws an exception

That's pretty awkward. If the object created using `clone()` keeps information on the image source (e.g. a handle on the original file) or you can't otherwise unlock the file while using the Bitmap instances, then you'll probably have to either save to a new file, or open from a temporary copy of the original.

Try this instead:

```
// ... make a copy of test.jpg called test_temp.jpg

Bitmap bmpOriginal = new Bitmap("C:\\test_temp.jpg"))
Bitmap bmpClone = (Bitmap)bmp.Clone();

// ... do stuff          
bmpClone.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipNone);

bmpClone.Save("C:\\test.jpg");

// ... cleanup
bmpOriginal.Dispose();
bmpClone.Dispose();
```

Comment: OK! But what if we really do need to have two copies of this Bitmap in memory (Two picture boxes one showing an "original" image, and one showing "modified" one, whenever -anytime- our user might click on Save button)?

Comment: Create two clones then and keep one unmodified.

Comment: @dtb:
Problem occurs on Save method, in the second block, "bmp" is still unmodified.
One solution is: creating a new Bitmap with same width+height+PixelFormat of source and drawing the source on it (implement cloning yourself), but is this solution wise? What is the efficient, fast and standard solution? How cloning of a Bitmap can be useful when it might result in such an exception?

Comment: `new Bitmap(Bitmap)` does exactly that: creating a new Bitmap with same width+height+PixelFormat of source and drawing the source on it

Comment: @dtb: It cannot be , because drawing on a Bitmap canvas is not always an option for creating a copy of a Bitmap. For example when the source bitmap is an 8 bit indexed one which Graphic.FromImage is not allowed for it, drawing is not possible, while new Bitmap(Bitmap) is working and possible.

Answer (score 5):

This is how I copy Bitmaps:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "CopyMemory")]
static extern void CopyMemory(IntPtr Destination, IntPtr Source, uint Length);

public static Bitmap KernellDllCopyBitmap(Bitmap bmp, bool CopyPalette = true)
{
    Bitmap bmpDest = new Bitmap(bmp.Width, bmp.Height, bmp.PixelFormat);

    if (!KernellDllCopyBitmap(bmp, bmpDest, CopyPalette))
        bmpDest = null;

    return bmpDest;
}


/// <summary>
/// Copy bitmap data.
/// Note: bitmaps must have same size and pixel format.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="bmpSrc">Source Bitmap</param>
/// <param name="bmpDest">Destination Bitmap</param>
/// <param name="CopyPalette">Must copy Palette</param>
public static bool KernellDllCopyBitmap(Bitmap bmpSrc, Bitmap bmpDest, bool CopyPalette = false)
{
    bool copyOk = false;
    copyOk = CheckCompatibility(bmpSrc, bmpDest);
    if (copyOk)
    {
        BitmapData bmpDataSrc;
        BitmapData bmpDataDest;

        //Lock Bitmap to get BitmapData
        bmpDataSrc = bmpSrc.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmpSrc.Width, bmpSrc.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bmpSrc.PixelFormat);
        bmpDataDest = bmpDest.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmpDest.Width, bmpDest.Height), ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, bmpDest.PixelFormat);
        int lenght = bmpDataSrc.Stride * bmpDataSrc.Height;

        CopyMemory(bmpDataDest.Scan0, bmpDataSrc.Scan0, (uint)lenght);

        bmpSrc.UnlockBits(bmpDataSrc);
        bmpDest.UnlockBits(bmpDataDest);

        if (CopyPalette && bmpSrc.Palette.Entries.Length > 0)
            bmpDest.Palette = bmpSrc.Palette;
    }
    return copyOk;
}

    public static bool CheckCompatibility(Bitmap bmp1, Bitmap bmp2)
    {
        return ((bmp1.Width == bmp2.Width) && (bmp1.Height == bmp2.Height) && (bmp1.PixelFormat == bmp2.PixelFormat));
    }
```

**## ImageCopyBenchmark ##**

Image Size: {Width=1024, Height=1024}.
Image PixelFormat: Format8bppIndexed.
Bitmap.Clone(): 0,00 ms (Not a DeepCopy... [Same pixel data - look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12709360/whats-the-difference-between-bitmap-clone-and-new-bitmapbitmap/12709443#12709443))
Bitmap.Clone() + RotateFlip (to guet a deep copy): 2,02 ms
KernellDllCopyBitmap: 0,52 ms (THE BEST!)
MarshalCopyBitmap: 2,21 ms

Comment: Works like a charm (apart from CheckCompatibility not being defined in your code snippet, but when removed it works).

Comment: Thanks Sebatian. I've added the CheckCompatibility now, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my vanity method:

```
    private static unsafe Bitmap DuplicateBitmap(Bitmap inputBitmap)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[inputBitmap.Height * inputBitmap.Width *
                            Image.GetPixelFormatSize(inputBitmap.PixelFormat) / 8];  

        fixed (byte* p = buffer)
        {
            BitmapData b1Data = new BitmapData()
            {
                Scan0 = (IntPtr)p,
                Height = inputBitmap.Height,
                Width = inputBitmap.Width,
                PixelFormat = inputBitmap.PixelFormat,
                Stride = inputBitmap.Width * Image.GetPixelFormatSize(inputBitmap.PixelFormat) / 8,
            }; 

            inputBitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(Point.Empty, inputBitmap.Size),
                ImageLockMode.ReadOnly | ImageLockMode.UserInputBuffer, inputBitmap.PixelFormat, b1Data); // copy out.   

            Bitmap b2 = new Bitmap(b1Data.Width, b1Data.Height, b1Data.Stride, inputBitmap.PixelFormat, b1Data.Scan0);

            inputBitmap.UnlockBits(b1Data); 

            return b2;
        }
    }
```

10% faster (depending on bitmap size...)