# lock image file in PictureBox

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

I load an image into a picturebox:

```
myPictureBox.Image = Image.FromFile(strImageFile);
```

and works perfectly, but the image file is locked and I can't manage until my application is closed..

I need, from another window of the program, save a new image to reload when this child window is closed..

Comment: Why don't you save it into a bitmap variable then use that to display

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Image.FromFile` will keep the File open which prevents access to the image file till the Image is disposed. If you want to release the lock, you need to keep the Image file in memory.

```
myPictureBox.Image = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(strImageFile)));
```

Comment: Reading image from `FileStream` instead of copying file content to `MemoryStream` first looks slightly more elegant.

Comment: @AndyKorneyev Elegant, yes. But you need to keep the `FileStream` open for the lifetime of the `Image`. That is same as calling `Image.FromFile`. It isn't going to help OP.

Answer (score 1):

An easy approach is to copy the image from the file to a new `Bitmap` and dispose the instance from the file after that. This is best done with a proper using construct:

```
using(var fromFile = Image.FromFile(strImageFile))
{
    myPictureBox.Image = new Bitmap(fromFile);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.image%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) load the image from the file and assign a cloned instance to the picture box.

> If you want to use the same image in multiple PictureBox controls, create a clone of the image for each PictureBox. Accessing the same image from multiple controls causes an exception to occur.

And to keep the file unlocked, just use it only for the clone time:

```
using ( var img = Image.FromFile( fileName ) )
{
    pictureBox2.Image = (Image) img.Clone();
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work. The clone retains the link to the original file.

Comment: @Nyerguds ReferenceSource says: [No, it does not](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Image.cs,331)

Comment: The actual cloning is done by the GDI+ system, which is also what does the original creation from file. That code says nothing, since you don't know what's inside `GdipCloneImage`.

Comment: @Nyerguds It says enough: Image class is not aware of the stream of the Bitmap class or the link to the original file. How can the link be copied without knowing it?

Comment: @Nyerguds BTW: Did you test it? I did, and it was working like a charm

Comment: Image class isn't what is manipulating the image. It is just a wrapper around GDI+ handling of the image. [Here's an extensive study.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12709360/whats-the-difference-between-bitmap-clone-and-new-bitmapbitmap/13935966#13935966)

Comment: Do note, "It works when I tested it" is a _very_ dangerous distinction from "it always works reliably", especially when external unmanaged systems like GDI+ are involved.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use `Image.FromStream` instead `Image.FromFile` and wrap stream you're reading from into `using` to make sure it will be released after you've done reading.

```
using (var stream = File.Open(strImageFile, FileMode.Open))
{
     myPictureBox.Image = Image.FromStream(stream);
}
```

Comment: That won't work I guess. You're closing the stream which the Image class is in need of. Think of it, what should happen when you call `Bitmap.SetPixel`.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Your guess is wrong. ;) Actually I've tested it, and it works - so it looks like you don't need to keep stream open after you've done with `Image.FromStream`

Comment: `Image.FromStream` [documentation says](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/93z9ee4x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that **You must keep the stream open for the lifetime of the Image.**

Comment: @SriramSakthivel As I've said - I tested this approach, and it works - image was dispayed correctly in picturebox and source file was not locked. More than - if you'll have a look into `Image` class sources (`EnsureSave` method which in fact reads image from stream) - you'll see there is no need for stream to be open after `EnsureSave` completion). So I don't know why MSDN insists on stream to be open after `Image.FromStream` completion.

Comment: The fact that it merely works doesn't mean it will continue to work. If documentation doesn't talks about it, we could assume it will work, but when docs explicitly says you must keep the stream open, you ought to keep it open. I'm afraid to use something which is against the documentation, because they could change the implementation anytime they want.

Comment: The only way to do this right is [a deep clone of the image data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48170549/395685) into a new `Bitmap` object created with a constructor without any kind of source argument.